# Android - Dynamic Radio Buttons Problem

Tags: android, list, arraylist, radio-button, radio-group

Please help me out on this one, Im trying to produce 2 radio buttons in a for loop dynamically depending upon the user input waht i want is to have radio buttons like

*Radio Button1 *RadioButton2

*Radio Button1 *RadioButton2

*Radio Button1 *RadioButton2

*Radio Button1 *RadioButton2

.
.
.

.

and so forth .. depending upon the loop !

Here is the snippet from my code its is working for only 2 radio buttons in one row only but when i increase the value of count . . i get android run time error of radiogroup child already having a parent. :S

```
List<RadioGroup> allradioGroup = new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();
RadioGroup radioGroup;

List<RadioButton> allRadio = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
RadioButton radioButton;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        /* Defining RadioGroup */
        radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
        radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

        allradioGroup.add(radioGroup);


        /* Displaying Radio Buttons */
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
            radioButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            radioButton.setId((j + 100));

            allRadio.add(radioButton);

            if (allRadio.get(j).getId() == 100) {
                radioButton.setText("private");
            } else if (allRadio.get(j).getId() == 101) {
                radioButton.setText("public");
            }

                allradioGroup.get(i).addView(allRadio.get(j), j,
                        layoutParams);
        }

        linear.addView(allradioGroup.get(i));

    }
```

Please HELP. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line: "allradioGroup.get(i).addView(allRadio.get(j), j, layoutParams);"

The parameter j will be in the range 0-1, also when you create your second row. You are trying to use allRadio.get(j) which on the second run will return the first radio button you created (which already has a parent). To fix this, replace "j" with: "i*2+j". That should fix it.

Comment: Ohhhhh, Yesssss my badd 
Thanks a lot Frenkenstain im marking this as the correct answer It worked like a charm Thanks a lot

Comment: Can You please also help me on fetching values from each radio button in each row . . This would help me a lot .. (:

Comment: You have all your RadioGroups in a List. You could loop through this:

`for(int i=0;i < count; i++){
   int id = allRadioGroup.get(i).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
   // Your first radiobutton ("private") has id 100, the second ("public) one has id 101 (as specified by you earlier)

   // do something depending on which radiobutton that is selected
}`

Comment: @Frenkenstain : I have not get the result by trying this example...
Actually, i tried the same as multiple RadioGroups with two RadioButtons.. Help me to catch this concept..!
Thank u.